# java concurrency - singleton design with a monitor thread

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, concurrency, singleton

I have a singleton class thus

```
public final class HandlerCache {
    //the cache maintains a handler per thread 
    private final Map<Thread, Handler> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private final Thread monitor;

    private static final HandlerCache INSTANCE = new HandlerCache();

    private HandlerCache() {
        monitor = new Thread() {
        //periodically monitor cache and close handlers when a thread has died
        }
        monitor.start()
    }

    public static HandlerCache getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public Handler getHandler() throws Exception {
        final Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
        Handler handler = cache.get(thread);

        if (!(handler == null))
            return handler;

        handler = HandlerFactory.get(getHandlerFromName(thread.getName()));
        cache.put(thread, handler);
        return handler;
    }

}
```

I am leaking the singleton instance to the monitor thread before the constructor is finished, what is the better way ?

Will making cache volatile will fix the issue ?

Comment: Any reasons not to use a ThreadLocal instead of your cache? (Side note: your implementation doesn't look thread safe)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I still have to maintain the mapping between the thread and the handler event in case of a ThreadLocal in order to close the handler when the thread has died. The thread class does not provide a hook that is invoked before the thread is stopped, can you please explain the thread safety issue, the one that I notice is the object being visible to the monitor thread before it is fully constructed, and thats the reason for this question

Comment: The getHandler method is not atomic - so the factory may be called me than once on the same thread - not sure if that's a problem (friends on the implementation if the factory).

Comment: Thats the intention, the threads calling the getHandler are part of a ThreadpoolExecutor, each time a Runnable is run in a thread from the Executor, the runnable invokes the getHandler, it gets the handler assigned for the thread

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by user2677485, you should be using a ThreadLocal and implement the initialValue method.  The other point is that the Handler implementation should implement the finalize method so that when it is being reclaimed by the GC this method will be called and you can clean up your resources.

The code can be simplified as something like the following:

```
public class HandlerCache {

   private static final handlers = new ThreadLocal<Handler>() {
        protected Handler initializeValue() {
              return HandlerFactory.get(...);
        }
   };

   public static Handler getHandler() {
        return handlers.get();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than starting the thread within the HandlerCache constructor, you could initialize the instance using a static function that would first construct the HandlerCache and then start the thread.